# Why did closing a question delete (most of) the answers?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I closed a question earlier: https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/serious-issue-with-this-site

As soon as I did so, 3 of the 4 answers were automatically locked and deleted by the Community user. The answer that wasn't deleted belonged to a moderator, and I assume that's why it wasn't deleted.

Even though the question isn't constructive the answers were good, so I undeleted and unlocked them.

Is this the expected behaviour? Does it have something to do with the question having been migrated from the main site? I seem to recall a post on Meta Stack Overflow discussing something similar a while back but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: Strangely, the [revision page for an answer that was deleted](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/2230/revisions) just shows the answer was undeleted, not deleted. (It's impossible to undelete a post that was not first deleted.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yeah it's a weird one. I'm wondering if it's even a bug maybe? I don't think it was a coincidence that Community locked and deleted those posts at exactly the same time as I closed the question :)

Comment: OK, I found the question on Meta Stack Overflow that explains what is done for rejected migrations. It is expected to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior, as reported in the accepted answer of [Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations)

- All migrated answers are deleted and locked on the destination site
- The migrated questions are locked on the destination site

The only answer that was not deleted was written in the destination site, not migrated. The fact it has been written by a moderator is a coincidence.

Comment: Good man that's exactly the post I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: There is still the fact the revision doesn't show the post as being deleted, but that is probably minor: If you see the post before it is undeleted, you notice it is deleted; if you see the post after it is undeleted, the entry about the post being undeleted implies the same post was first deleted.